# Visualising 1 variable with static value

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I calculated a mean sentiment score. I would like to visualise the sentiment score based on a scale from -1.0 to 1.0. Is it possible to do this in python with a libary like seaborn? If so, I would like to know how..

I cant seem to manage to make it. My ideal output would be a bar chart with x axis -1.0 to 1.0, and a bar in the middle aligned left starting from -1.0 stopping at the sentiment score value.

```
Numbers scale sentiment score
0      -1.0   0.065179
1      -0.9   0.065179
2      -0.8   0.065179
etc..
```

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python plot bar graph", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
apparently you can do:

```
plt.barh(data[:,0],data[:,2],left=-1)
```

but this also shifts all your data, so you can try:

```
offset = -1
plt.barh(data[:,0],data[:,2]-offset,left=offest)
```

seems to work

Original post:
Not sure how to start from -1, but this is a start:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.barh(data[:,0],data[:,2])
plt.xlim((-1,1))
plt.show()
```